# C++ : Escaping quotes for std::string behaves differently on Linux vs Windows

Tags: c++, linux, stdstring

So , my problem seemed an easy one to begin with. 
I'm interested in saving the exact cmd line arguments i'm receiving in the main() of my program because of some inherited code that i'm supposed to use that needs access to it but gets called further down inside the code. I won't get into more detail here.

The main problem is the fact that if i pass a path that contains spaces, that path needs to be placed between double quotes. Those double quotes get stripped away by argv[] so i need to add them back.

So i did something like the following:

```
string buff;
buff.assign("");
for(int i = 0; i < m_argc; i++)
{
    buff.append("\"");
    buff.append(m_argv[i]);
    buff.append("\" ");            
}
```

Which on WINDOWS returns what i expect, something like this :

```
"C:\...\myProg.exe" "-s" "-i" "c:\...\file with spaces.dat".
```

Which is what i expect.

On LINUX, however i get something like this:

```
\"/.../myProg.exe\" \"-s\" \"-i\" \"/.../file with spaces.dat\"
```

Which is completely unexpected to me and further messes up any processing thereafter

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

EDIT, as requested , a working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

int main(int argc, char* argv[], char* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    std::string buff;
    buff.assign("");

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (i != argc-1)
        {
            if (i > 0 && (strcmp(argv[i-1],"-i") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i-1],"-o") == 0))
            {
                buff.append("\"");
                buff.append(argv[i]);
                buff.append("\" ");
            }
            else
            {
                buff.append(argv[i]);
                buff.append(" ");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (i > 0 && (strcmp(argv[i-1],"-i") == 0 || strcmp(argv[i-1],"-o") == 0))
            {
                buff.append("\"");
                buff.append(argv[i]);
                buff.append("\"");
            }
            else
                buff.append(argv[i]);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "contents of buff: \n" << buff.c_str() << std::endl;

    return nRetCode;
}
```

I get a correct output from this one:

```
/.../myProg -s -i "/.../file with spaces"
```

As PaulMcKenzie and Igor Tandetnik suggested, that's just how the debugger reports the contents of the string.

Thank you for the help, everyone

Comment: Please post rest of your program, preferably a [mcve].

Comment: How do you determine that? Are you looking at the string in the debugger? It could simply be the difference in how different debuggers choose to represent the same contents.

Comment: When you are passing an argument with spaces like for example
`program.exe argument with spaces` why not pass it as `program.exe "argument with spaces"`? Is there a reason why you do not want to do this?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes i'm looking at the string contents while debugging (cgdb for linux)

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla i am passing my args between quotes , but inside the program. I also want to save the arguments because classes that are being called outside the scope of main() need those arguments, so i need to add the quotes again.

Comment: @Duppy -- *Which is completely unexpected to me* -- What is unexpected to you?  Looks like a perfectly good string to me.  Also forget about the debugger -- what is the *actual* string being returned?  You maybe just being fooled by what some particular debugger is showing when attempting to show user-placed quotation marks.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie well i would expect a result like the one i'm getting under Windows. On Linux is as if the backslash that is used to escape the next char is being escaped by another backslash. Furthermore, that is the exact string i'm getting back because other code that follows stops working correctly

Comment: @Duppy -- Again, are you looking at those strings in a debugger?  If you are stop doing that.  Write the strings to a file or something similar and actually see what the string is.  A debugger, when given a string that contains quotes, can show wildly different interpretations of that string depending on the debugger you're using.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a [mcve] of your problem.  It shouldn't be hard to provide a `main()` with suitable `m_argc` and `m_argv` and a suitable output statement.  Then we can all see that this is a real difference, and not just something you're observing in an interactive debugger.

Comment: BTW, you might want to also consider what to do if your strings might contain `"` or `$` or `\ `.

Answer (score 1):

The linux OS uses `/` for directory paths; Windows uses `\`. Nothing you can do about that.

The OS simply delivers all paths to you the way it knows them.

Comment: Windows or Linux paths are not the issue here